# How to construct this metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Please give an example of metric space that there are two open balls $B(x,\rho_1) \subset B(y,\rho_2)$ for $\rho_1>\rho_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the interval $(-3,3)$. Let $B_1 $ be the open ball of radius $3$ centered at $x=0$ and let $B_2$ be the open ball of radius 4 centered at $x=2$.

Comment: Thank you,it's so obvious by this!

Answer (score 2):

If your $\subset$ allows the possibility of equality (i.e. $\subset$ means $\subseteq$), then letting $d$ be the discrete metric on any non-empty set $X$, we have that $B(x,3)=B(y,2)=X$ for any $x,y\in X$.

Comment: And if equality is excluded, this is impossible...

Comment: True, just thought I'd throw this out there though :)

Comment: It's impossible in a normed space...

Comment: $\subset$ should allow eaqulity,I think :)

Answer (score 1):

The example is quite simple, take $X=[0,1]$ with the induced metric then take $B(0,10^6)\subset B(0,2)$.

Comment: Ha,$\rho_1$ is so big :)

Comment: I like to put a million in my calculus as well the number 13!

Answer (score 1):

Take a discrete space with the discrete metric $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\ne y$. Then $B(x,1/3)=B(x,1/2)$.